# If F is a finite field, then $F^F=P_F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The hint is: Let F has as elements $a_1,...,a_n$. Note that if $$f_i(x)=c(x-a_1)...(x-a_{i-1})(x-a_{i+1})...(x-a_n)$$, then $f_i(a_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and the value $f_i(a_j)$ can be controlled by the choice of $c\in F$. Use this to show that every function on F is a polynomial function.

Using Fraleigh’s seventh edition of A First Course in Abstract Algebra. Need help with problem 22.31c. I’m completely lost. Thank you!

Comment: Explain your notation: what do $\;F^F\,,\,\,P_F\;$ mean, for a finite field $\;F\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I think $F^F$ denotes the set of all functions from $F \to F$ (which is standard notation) and $P_F$ denotes the set of all polynomial functions from $F \to F$.

Comment: Alex Vong is correct.

Comment: Do you know about interpolation polynomials?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and consider the map
$$
v\colon F[x]\to F^n \qquad v(f)=(f(a_1),f(a_2),\dots,f(a_n))
$$
which is a ring homomorphism. Its kernel is generated by
$$
g(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\dots(x-a_n)
$$
so $v$ is surjective by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Can you finish?

Comment: To be honest... I don’t think I can.

Comment: @AmandaJohnson The rings $F^n$ and $F^F$ are the same thing.

Comment: So $f_i (x)= cg(x)$?

Comment: @AmandaJohnson I don’t think you were given a good hint. My approach is different: what I get is a surjection from the polynomials to the functions.